# R can someone explain to me why one is looping in the list and the other is not?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have list of string and I would like to loop into each one.

The main issue is the list is someonwhat like this

```r
list <- list("word", "word", "two, word", "word")
```

My attemp is to make the item with two word a list of its own.
IE:

```r
list <- list("word", "word", ["two", "word"], "word")
```

So in order to do that I want to loop through and reassign things.

Now I manage to loop on the first level no problem

```r
list <- list("word", "word", "two, word", "word")
```

the issue arise when trying to loop through the second layer.

See my code below.
technically both techniques should return the same items but for some reason they do not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QGY1.png)

I was expecting for both techniques IE

```
  for(j in 1:length(TacticList[i])){
    for(k in 1:length(TacticList[i][j])){
      print(TacticList[i][j][k])
    }
  }
```

and

```
 for (element in TacticList[i]){
    for (thing in element){
      print(thing)
    }
```

to return the same values.

Although in my current situation I need the first technique to return the value given by the second technique.
Given that the first techniques as pointers it will be usefull for me to reassign data.

Comment: Do you want `lapply(list, \(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ",\\s+")))`

Comment: Many thanks to all the answers, they worked but I am faced with an other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the multi-`for` thing, but perhaps this works:

```r
L <- list("word", "word", "two, word", "word")
out <- rapply(L, strsplit, split = "[, ]+", how = "replace")
str(out)
# List of 4
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr "word"
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr "word"
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "two" "word"
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr "word"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
lapply(list, \(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ",\\s+")))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "word"

[[2]]
[1] "word"

[[3]]
[1] "two"  "word"

[[4]]
[1] "word"
```